# Bootstrap Modal disabling text fields from child DIV

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a popup within a bootstrap modal by simply creating a div, hiding it and then showing it onclick; I set the z-index to 9999 so it would appear on top of all modals. When you click the button to show the div there's now problem but when it's within a modal the text and textarea fields are disabled, you cannot enter anything.

The source can be found on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/rMdLZ/15/) but for some reason the JavaScript doesn't work for the popup I made (any ideas?)

You can find a complete working demo at [this webpage.](http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/base_fake_modal.html)

NONWORKING JS IN FIDDLE

```
        function showBigProb() {
    if (document.getElementById("ShowProbBtn").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("BigNewProblem").style.display="block";

    }
}

    function closeBigProb() {
    if (document.getElementById("closeProbBtn").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("BigNewProblem").style.display="none";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but its got something to do with `tabindex="-1"` being on the modal, as soon as that is removed it starts working.